# Stop Android AVD showing location change toast

Tags: android-virtual-device, android-location, android-toast

Whenever I change location on my AVD, whether it's via telnet or in DDMS I get a system toast message saying 'my current location is .....'

It's really annoying as it's covering up my app which is showing these details.

I can't find a way of removing it and searching didn't show much up. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checked on my AVDs with Android 4.4 and I can safely say this toast is not part of Android system, and I can only assume this toast is being shown probably by a tool or an application you previously installed on the AVD.

My suggestion for you is to track LogCat whenever you send a mock location and see which events are being recorded to log when the toast is being displayed. If such an event is recorded, track it to the source package and remove that package by running `adb uninstall <package_name>`. If this fails, try creating a new AVD and send a mock location to it before making any changes to the machine, then incrementally install whatever tools and applications you need to identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any extra libraries or modules setup with your application? My first thoughts would be that some other library you added may have a toast built in and their code is calling it at some point. If you do try looking in those libraries and remove the toast code.